# adding menu items in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, menuitem

I am using wp_nav_menu() and I want to add the search box as a part of the menu.

I am having trouble figuring it out and was hoping for some assistance:

My code:

```
        <?php 
        $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false);
        wp_nav_menu( $args ); 
        ?>
```

Now I want to add an additional <li> element to the end or the menu <ul> and all I want in the <li> is the output of:

```
        <?php get_search_form();?>
```

Can this be done?

functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'register_top_menu');

function register_top_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('primary', __('Top Menu', 'leeaenergy'));
}


add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search', 10, 2);

function add_search($items, $args) {

    if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    return $items . '<li>'.get_search_form().'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need to use a filter. Add the following code to your functions.php file. Change the `theme_location` to whatever is set up for your current theme:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search', 10, 2 );

function add_search( $items, $args ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location == 'primary' ) {
        return $items . '<li>' . get_search_form() . '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that but nothing has changed what else do I need to have in place?

Comment: That's all you need. Try removing the if statement and see if it adds it to all menus

Comment: the problem is with the menu not registering... I think it was just displaying all pages - I finally "sort of" have the menu regsitered and I found another way to do it but that is presenting issues as well... F*ing painful!!! Anyway, I'll keep battling... thanks

Comment: BTW I can't test this until I figure out this menu stuff so I can't confirm or deny that it works.

Comment: You have to use get_search_form( false ) to prevent it echoing.